# Prepopulating form from get/post

Tags: php, forms

I'm not fluent in english and I'm newbie in HTML so i'm i don't know how can i explain. x.x

This is the **send.php:**

```
<?php 
$user="user"; 
$password="password123"; 
$url="http://www.website.com:1114/?user=" .$user. "&password=" .$password; 
$get = file_get_contents($url); 
echo 
$get;
?>
```

**Will redirect but won't show the link**

```
http://www.website.com:1114/?user=username&password=password123
```

**Form:**

```
    <form action=send.php" method="post">
   <p class="number-input">
Number: <br/>
<select name="PhoneNUmber" id="prefix">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0905">0905</option>
<option value="0906">0906</option>
<option value="0907">0907</option>
<option value="0908">0908</option>
<option value="0909">0909</option>
<option value="0910">0910</option>
<option value="0912">0912</option>
<option value="0915">0915</option>
<option value="0916">0916</option>
<option value="0917">0917</option>
<option value="0918">0918</option>
<option value="0919">0919</option>
<option value="0920">0920</option>
<option value="0921">0921</option>
<option value="0922">0922</option>
<option value="0923">0923</option>
<option value="0926">0926</option>
<option value="0927">0927</option>
<option value="0928">0928</option>
<option value="0929">0929</option>
<option value="0930">0930</option>
<option value="0932">0932</option>
<option value="0933">0933</option>
<option value="0935">0935</option>
<option value="0936">0936</option>
<option value="0937">0937</option>
<option value="0938">0938</option>
<option value="0939">0939</option>
<option value="0942">0942</option>
<option value="0943">0943</option>
<option value="0946">0946</option>
<option value="0947">0947</option>
<option value="0948">0948</option>
<option value="0949">0949</option>
<option value="0989">0989</option>
<option value="0996">0996</option>
<option value="0997">0997</option>
<option value="0999">0999</option>
</select><input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" id="phone" size="7" maxlength="7"/>
</p>
    Message: <input type="text" name="Text">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

**The link will be:**

```
http://www.website.com:1114/?user=username&password=password123&PhoneNumber=" "&Text=" "
```

**But will show in the browser:**

```
http://www.othersite.com/send.php?PhoneNumber=" "&Text=" "
```

**Example Image:**
[Example Picture Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWmfO.png)

**Will Get Into:**

```
http://www.othersire.com/send.php?PhoneNumber=09052093489&Text=Hi
```

please help me.

Comment: What is your question???

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but if you are trying to do a redirect, you need header.

```
<?php
 $user="user"; 
$password="password123"; 
$url="http://www.website.com:1114/?user=" .$user. "&password=" .$password; 
header("Location: $url");
```